# Get textfield's cursor position

Tags: flutter

I'm using textfield in my flutter code. I'm trying to use my own made keyboard instead of the default phones keyboard (Hiding phones keyboard). To edit or modify the text in the textfield, I need to know the current position of the cursor in the field. how can I get that?

```dart
String _textInput = '';

void inputCharecterToTextField(int pressedKey) {
  _textInput += pressedKey.toString();
  setState(() {});
  _textEditingController.text = _textInput;
}
```

This is what I'm doing to input text in the field. But user can change cursor position. So, for modification of the text, I need the cursor position.